# Auto-Orient, Wrong Rotation on Last Keyframe in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I have an issue with the **Transform** | **Auto-orient** option. I does work in general but at the very last keyframe the object's rotation changes apruptly.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I avoid that?

I am using After Effects CS4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The rotation was caused by an expression I used to loop the animation

```
loopOut("cycle")
```